# Does defining _id as a custom random string in mongoose instead of MongoDB's default ObjectId make us lose the indexing?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, time-complexity, mongoose-schema

I am using a new auth library called Lucia. Lucia requires you to have some standard schemas. Here is an example of the User schema.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const User = mongoose.model(
    "User",
    new mongodb.Schema(
        {
            _id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        } as const,
        { _id: false }
    )
);
```

Does setting a custom random string for the _id property make us lose the indexing that MongoDB does for ObjectId? I would also like to understand the behavior of `{_id: false}` since omitting it didn't have any negative affects.

Comment: "lose the indexing that MongoDB does for ObjectId" - no. Because it doesn't do any special indexing. Since mongodb documents do not have schema, mongodb indexes can't know what type of values you are going to write. They will work regardless..

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of your index will not "lose the index" because an index in a single field is independant from the type. See the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-single/) for more info about single index.

The following syntax it will stop add an _id field in your Schema by default. For more info, see this [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id).

```
{ _id: false }
```